# Multi sheets export using rdlc .

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rdlc

I am creating my report in rdlc format and able to export in excel and pdf (inbuild function of rdlc) this work fine but i want to export each column in diffrent sheets of excel please guide  me in this .

My report look like this

```
    First   Second  Third   Sbtraction
    100 200 300 -400
    800 400 50  350
Total   900 600 350 -50
```

I want  First column  in one sheet and Second  coulmn in next sheet

Comment: Iterate thru the collection, create an array per column, create one worksheet per array? I dunno exactly what you want. Maybe with more information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've figured out to export an RDLC report to multiple excel sheets is by using page breaks inside my RDLC report.So you could perhaps create a new report where you split the table into different tables for each column, adding page-breaks at the end of each table.
This will look horrible in the report viewer but will automatically export to  excel with multiple sheets.

Another solution, perhaps a better one is by exporting the DataSet directly into excel. Here is a great tutorial explaining how to do this for multiple sheets.

> [Export multiple DataSets to multiple Excel sheets dynamically formatted according to the record's data type](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335589/Export-Multiple-Datasets-to-Multiple-Excel-sheets)